# How to move with an animation a ContentControl WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, wpf-controls, contentcontrol

I'm trying to simulate this effect on an `OnLoad` page:

[image]

The blue square represents the beggining transaction, and the red one the end of the animation.

In WPF, that square is for me a `ContentControl`, and I have tried this:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFShapes.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="802" Width="1557" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- This effect makes the main container appear the first time smoothly -->
    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="animatedBorder">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0.0">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="900*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="460" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="850*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="150,0,150,0" Name="contentControl1" Width="Auto" Height="650" >
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource animatedBorder}"
            Name="movableBorder"
            Background="WhiteSmoke"
                >
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect 
                BlurRadius="10"
                Color="#877b77"
                Opacity="100"
                ShadowDepth="10"
                Direction="-50" />
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

My idea was, give the `ContentControl` a beggining position (the blue square), and when it's loaded, traslate it with a smooth effect from position 1 (blue square) to position 2 (red square). I tried the `RenderTransform`, but I think I couldn't find enough information and I feel a bit lost.

You can see that I have a `ContentControl` that has a border that appears with a fade effect. This `Border` effect happens, but I'm a bit lost on how to make the `ContentControl` appear as I want.

I don't have any C# code til now.

Any idea on what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ThicknessAnimation` to animate the `Margin` of your content control.

Here is an example, it will animate on mouse over, but you will be able to see how to use the `ThicknessAnimation`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="317.3" Width="337" x:Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10,107,60,10">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:1.5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="10,107,60,10" To="36,48,34,69" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
       </Border>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Perfect friend! I could change it a little bit so it does exactly what I want changing the <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"><Trigger.EnterActions> with  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded"> and it does exactly what I need! Thaaanks so much! ;)